# Hausdorff's maximality principle lemma in Rudin Real and Complex analysis

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here's the lemma that is needed before proving the Hausdorff's maximality principle (in Rudin's real and complex analysis appendix):

> **Lemma** Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is a nonempty collection of subsets of a set $X$ such that the union of every subchain of $\mathcal{F}$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}$. Suppose $g$ is a function which associates to each $A \in \mathcal{F}$ a set $g(A) \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $A \subset g(A)$ and $g(A) - A$ consists of at most one element. Then there exists an $A \in \mathcal{F}$ for which $g(A) = A$.

In the proof, it first defines a *tower*:

> Fix $A_0 \in \mathcal{F}$. Call a subcollection $\mathcal{F}'$ of $\mathcal{F}$ a tower if $\mathcal{F}'$ has the following three properties: 
> (a) $A_0 \in \mathcal{F}'$
> (b) The union of every subchain of $\mathcal{F}'$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}'$
> (c) If $A \in \mathcal{F}'$, then also $g(A) \in \mathcal{F}'$

In the proof, we let $\mathcal{F}_0$ be the intersection of all towers which is also a tower (proof is trivial). Then we go on to define two more collection of sets:

> Let $\Gamma$ be the collection of all $C \in \mathcal{F}_0$ such that every $A \in \mathcal{F}_0$ satisfies either $A \subset C$ or $C \subset A$.
> For each $C \in \Gamma$, let $\Phi(C)$ be the collection of all $A \in \mathcal{F}_0$ such that either $A \subset C$ or $g(C) \subset A$.

In other words
\begin{align*}
\Gamma &= \{ C \in \mathcal{F}_0 : A \subset C \text{ or } C \subset A \; \text{ for every } A \in \mathcal{F}_0 \}\\
\Phi(C) &= \{ A \in \mathcal{F}_0: A \subset C \text{ or } g(C) \subset A \}
\end{align*}

Now in the proof, it proves that $\Phi(C)$ is a tower by showing that it meets all three properties shown above. The first two properties can be shown easily. For the third property, we do the following:

> If $A \in \Phi(C)$ there are three possibilities: Either $A \subset C$ and $A \neq C$, or $A = C$, or $g(C) \subset A$. If $A$ is a proper subset of $C$, then $C$ cannot be a proper subset of $g(A)$, otherwise $g(A) - A$ would contain at least two elements; since $C \in \Gamma$, it follows that $g(A) \subset C$. If $A = C$, then $g(A) = g(C)$. If $g(C) \subset A$, then also $g(C) \subset g(A)$ since $A \subset g(A)$. Thus $g(A) \in \Phi(C)$, and we have proved that $\Phi(C)$ is a tower. The minimality of $\mathcal{F}_0$ implies now that $\Phi(C) = \mathcal{F}_0$, for every $C \in \Gamma$

I am stuck on the last claim in the proof where it says **The minimality of $\mathcal{F}_0$ implies now that $\Phi(C) = \mathcal{F}_0$, for every $C \in \Gamma$**. What exactly does the minimality mean in this context and how does that lead to the equality? My guess is that $\Phi(C)$ is the smallest tower containing $C$, and since $\mathcal{F}_0$ is also the smallest tower containing $C$, they must be equal?

Also the proof says that

> In other words, if $A \in \mathcal{F}_0$ and $C \in \Gamma$, then either $A \subset C$ or $g(C) \subset A$. But this says that $g(C) \in \Gamma$. Hence $\Gamma$ is a tower, and the minimality of $\mathcal{F}_0$ shows that $\Gamma = \mathcal{F}_0$. It follows from the definition of $\Gamma$ that $\mathcal{F}_0$ is totally ordered.

Here, since $\Phi(C) = \mathcal{F}_0$, for any $A \in \mathcal{F}_0$, either $A \subset C$ or $g(C) \subset A$. Since $C \subset g(C)$, we can say that for all $A \in \mathcal{F}_0$, either $A \subset g(C)$ or $g(C) \subset A$, which implies that $g(C) \in \Gamma$. Hence this satisfies property (c) of the definition of tower. Here they again use the minimality condition to show that $\Gamma = \mathcal{F}_0$ which I'm not sure how they did. And how does this result in $\mathcal{F}_0$ being totally ordered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly does the minimality mean in this context and how does that lead to the equality?

Recall that $\mathscr F_0$ is the intersection of all towers. Hence it is a subset of every tower, and is thus the smallest possible tower. But $\Phi(C)$ is also a tower, and a subset of $\mathscr F_0$. Since they are both subsets of the other, $\Phi(C) = \mathscr F_0$.

The same is true for $\Gamma$. By its definition, it is a subset of $\mathscr F_0$, and now you have shown it is a tower, so  $\mathscr F_0$ is a subset of it. So $\Gamma = \mathscr F_0$.

You will encounter this sort of construction a lot. If you have a property on a collection of sets which is preserved under intersection (including infinite intersections), then the intersection of all sets with the property will be the smallest set having that property. Similarly if a property is preserved under unions, then the union of all sets having the property will be the largest set having that property. Two simple examples involving a set $A$ in a topological space:

- The union of all open sets within $A$ is the largest open set in $A$. This is the interior of $A$.
- The intersection of all closed sets containing $A$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$. This is the closure of $A$.

As for totally ordered, $\subset$ is already a partial order on $\mathscr F_0$, so to get totally ordered, all that is needed is to show that every two elements of $\mathscr F_0$ are comparable. But $\Gamma$ is by definition every set which is comparable to all sets in $\mathscr F_0$. And since it turns out $\Gamma$ is $\mathscr F_0$, that means every set in $\mathscr F_0$ is comparable to every other.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: @paulsinclair Please note, in the proof it is mentioned that: "A proper Subcollection of $\mathscr F_0$ is not a Tower". Can you please clarify and show how this is the case. Am happy to make this a separate question if necessary?

Comment: @texmex - since $\scr F_0$ is the intersection of all towers that are subsets of $\scr F$. Any subset $\scr G$ of $\scr F_0$ is also a subset of $\scr F$. If $\scr G$ is a tower, then it is one of the towers in the intersection defining $\scr F_0$, and thus $\scr F_0 \subseteq \scr G$. Thus it can only be that $\scr G = \scr F_0$, not a proper subset.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks for this very helpful answer. I will be in touch if I have more questions.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Could you please clarify this related question? It is stated that $A_{0}\subset A$ if $A\in\mathscr{F}_{0}$. Suppose there is $A\in\mathscr{F}_{0}$
such that $A_{0}\not\subset A$. Then all towers need to contain $A$
since $\mathscr{F}_{0}$ is the intersection of all towers. But we
can have valid a tower without containing $A$ contradicting the definition
that $\mathscr{F}_{0}$ is the intersection of all towers.

Comment: @texmex - could you please clarify that question? What is $A_0$? Where is this "stated"? Why would the existence of a subset of a set in $A_0$ imply the existences of a tower in $\scr F$? Why do you claim that $A_0 \subset A$, then suppose $A_0 \not\subset A$? Did no one teach you that you should not use the same variable in the same context to mean two different things?

Comment: @PaulSinclair, Please note the $A_{0}$ is the same one given in the definition of a tower. Each tower contains a $A_{0}$ by definition. This is given above in the original question. It is stated in the proof of the Lemma for this question that $A_{0}\subset A$ if $A\in\mathscr{F}_{0}$. We are trying to prove this by contradiction. Perhaps should have stated the contradiction part above. So the naming of the variables should be fine. Please let me know if I should clarify this further.

Comment: @texmex - okay, I think I understand now, except what is it that you are asking about? You assumed the existence of an $A$ with $A_0\not\subset A$, and arrived at a contradiction, thus showing that no such $A$ can exist. What is your concern? Is it why there is a valid tower not containing $A$?  $\{A_0\}\cup \{g^n(A_0)\mid n\in \Bbb N\}$ is such a tower, which cannot contain $A$ since $A_0 \subset g^n(A_0)$ for all $n$.

Comment: I guess I need to be a little more careful than that, as it isn't closed under unions of subchains. But for that you could define that set as $G(A_0)$, then define $\mathscr G = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty G^n(A_0)$ to get a tower.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, Thanks again for your helpful clarifications. I will digest this and be in touch if anything else.